# data:image/gif;base64 <img> source in ie7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I would like to make use of embedded base64 images in ie7.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mfPnK/

I tried including "ie9.js", without success:

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/source/browse/test/object-base64.html

Anyone know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using an `<object>` tag instead of `<img>` as shown in the home page of [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/source/browse/test/object-base64.html)?

Comment: My (now deleted) answer wasn't true. IE9 in IE7 mode seems to support base64 embedding where genuine IE7 doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add base64 support to IE7 using a library. This is a feature that can't be added using JavaScript.

Comment: Guess so, any aternatives if i want to embed an image in ie7?

Comment: @Johan see [Images in one file under IE6 WITHOUT php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663855/5664015#5664015)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in IE7, however you can use MTHML instead to get inline images, here's a good post on it: http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/.

Comment: My problem is that i dont know if my users will have internet connection, so i cant link to external images. And i dont want to use any other files besides my html, so i can use an image folder or similar.

Comment: I don't see why having multiple files is a problem for offline users, but if for some reason it is; the technique in the above link does enable images to be defined in the the same file as the html.

Comment: @Johan I think this looks good and will do exactly what you need to do?